# What does the "exclude" Tag in Magento 2's view.xml file do

Tags: magento2, theme

The Magento 2 "blank" theme includes the following tag hierarchy.

```
<exclude>
    <item type="file">Lib::jquery/jquery-ui-1.9.2.js</item>
    <item type="file">Lib::jquery/jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js</item>
    <item type="file">Lib::jquery/jquery.details.js</item>
    <item type="file">Lib::jquery/jquery.details.min.js</item>
    <item type="file">Lib::jquery/jquery.hoverIntent.js</item>
    <item type="file">Lib::jquery/jquery.min.js</item>
    <item type="file">Lib::mage/captcha.js</item>
    <item type="file">Lib::mage/dropdown_old.js</item>
    <item type="file">Lib::mage/list.js</item>
    <item type="file">Lib::mage/loader_old.js</item>
    <item type="file">Lib::mage/webapi.js</item>
    <item type="file">Lib::moment.js</item>
    <item type="file">Lib::requirejs/require.js</item>
    <item type="file">Lib::date-format-normalizer.js</item>
    <item type="file">Lib::legacy-build.min.js</item>
    <item type="directory">Lib::modernizr</item>
    <item type="directory">Lib::tiny_mce</item>
    <item type="directory">Lib::varien</item>
    <item type="directory">Lib::jquery/editableMultiselect</item>
    <item type="directory">Lib::jquery/jstree</item>
    <item type="directory">Lib::jquery/fileUploader</item>
    <item type="directory">Lib::css</item>
    <item type="directory">Lib::lib</item>
    <item type="directory">Lib::extjs</item>
    <item type="directory">Lib::prototype</item>
    <item type="directory">Lib::scriptaculous</item>
    <item type="directory">Lib::mage/requirejs</item>
    <item type="directory">Lib::mage/adminhtml</item>
    <item type="directory">Lib::mage/backend</item>
    <item type="directory">Magento_Swagger::swagger-ui</item>
</exclude>
```

What is this here for.  i.e. what's being excluded from what?  Where and when does Magento 2 system code access this information?

Comment: It's evaluated in the same place where we excluded you from this information, Alan.

Comment: @benmarks Being excluded from the implementation details of a particular system makes me feel closer to most employees of Magento Inc. ;)

Answer (score 13):

Magento 2 supported bundling of js/html  files. `<exclude>` node define list of resources that should not be bundled. see `\Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Bundle\Manager` for details

Comment: Bundling?  What does that mean?  Magento supports a ruby package manager?

Comment: 'Bundling' means combining multiple resources into a single package/file. It is frontend performance improvement by decreasing quantity of request to server.

Comment: Which bundling does exclude apply to?  There seem to be multiple places Magento "bundles up" frontend assets.

Comment: I'm guessing if it's a .js file, it'll load that individually. If it isn't excluded, it'll be merged in a JS file like we're used to with the JS Merge option in M1. If a dir is excluded, all files in that dir will be loaded individually.

Comment: Update; this method confirms my suspicion; https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/077584c99ebb8007cad176c3b9a0144a05c259cd/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Asset/Bundle.php#L229

Answer (score 12):

This configuration is accessed when you execute the command

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

In the function `\Magento\Deploy\Model\Deployer::deployFile`, the following two calls are of interest:

```
$this->assetPublisher->publish($asset);
$this->bundleManager->addAsset($asset);
```

The first call will add the asset file to the filesystem. I'm not sure what the second call does exactly. That's where I'm getting lost.

However, if you follow this second call, you will find some validation functions, which eventually lead to

```
// \Magento\Framework\Config\View

/**
 * Get excluded file list
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getExcludedFiles()
{
    $items = $this->getItems();
    return isset($items['file']) ? $items['file'] : [];
}

/**
 * Get excluded directory list
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getExcludedDir()
{
    $items = $this->getItems();
    return isset($items['directory']) ? $items['directory'] : [];
}

/**
 * Get a list of excludes
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function getItems()
{
    $this->initData();
    return isset($this->data['exclude']) ? $this->data['exclude'] : [];
}
```

But, there are a few issues here.

First, the function `\Magento\Framework\Config\View::getItems` always seems to return an empty array.

Second, the function `\Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Bundle\Manager::isExcludedFile` will always return `false`

```
/**
 * Check if asset file is excluded
 *
 * @param string $filePath
 * @param LocalInterface $asset
 * @return bool
 */
protected function isExcludedFile($filePath, $asset)
{
    /** @var $asset LocalInterface */
    $filePathInfo = $this->splitPath($filePath);
    if ($filePathInfo && $this->compareModules($filePathInfo, $asset)) {
        return $asset->getSourceFile() == $filePathInfo['excludedPath'];
    }
    return false;
}
```

Because `$asset->getSourceFile()` is the absolute path to the asset file, while `$filePathInfo['excludedPath']` is a relative path.

So, as far as I can see the the `<exclude>` configuration will not work anyway. But if it would work the asset would be excluded from the `\Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Bundle`.

Comment: Does this functionality now work in Magento 2.3+?