# Is there a standard way to make add a config on theme scope?

Tags: theme, configuration, magento2.2.6

To solve [a problem in an FOSS extension](https://github.com/MNGemignani/magento2_requirejs_disable/issues/1#issuecomment-465141315) I need to introduce a configuration settings with the scope "theme".

Is there a standard way do to such?

I was thinking about extended in the `theme.xml` but this is locked down by the style sheet.

Another option I see to add an array config in the backened, where I can specific theme and config.

But I am wondering if there is a standard way to do such.

Comment: https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/How-to-extend-core-XSD-schema-quot-view-xsd-quot/td-p/35680

Answer (score 2):

I see two options:

- use the `etc/view.xml` `<vars>` tag inside the theme
- create a new configuration file type `etc/disable_requirejs.xml` inside the theme

Other option

Use excluded files for this - and exclude them from require JS config

[What does the "exclude" Tag in Magento 2's view.xml file do](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96510/what-does-the-exclude-tag-in-magento-2s-view-xml-file-do)